# ¿Cómo acceder a los valores de un array asociativo usando su posición de index en JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente **array** en **JS**

`let x = [{Nombre:'Juan', Calle:'Reforma'}, {Nombre:'Ignacio', Calle:'Tulipan'}];`

Lo itero sin problemas con un **for** por el **nombre de sus claves** con:

```
for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    console.log(x[i]['Nombre']);
}
```

Me preguntaba si sería posible **acceder al mismo valor** pero usando el **index** en lugar de su **nombre de clave**, por ejemplo:

```
for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    console.log(x[i][0]);
}
```

Intenté hacerlo con doble **for** pero no tuve éxito.

```
for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
        console.log(x[i][j]);
    }
}
```

También intenté transformar en **objeto de claves el array** pero tampoco me funcionó, tal vez lo hicel mal, gracias por su ayuda!!!

Comment: Puede preguntar para que quieres hacer eso?

Comment: @alanfcm Sé que podría ser algo innecesario en este caso, pero estoy trabajando con unos arrays un poco largos y como ya se que datos traerá el arreglo pues sería mas fácil y rápido con solo obtener el valor por el Index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo utilizando `Object.values()` asi:

```js
let x = [{Nombre:'Juan', Calle:'Reforma'}, {Nombre:'Ignacio', Calle:'Tulipan'}];

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    let y = Object.values(x[i]);
    console.log(y[0]);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que buscaba!!!